# Why am I unable to change opacity of background images in Blender 2.82 (sub 7)?

Tags: image, transparency

Current animation student, need to learn everything about latest Blender engine. Using Pluralsight to supplement on-ground college courses. Current module requests opacity change of background reference image. Unable to comply. Blender v2.82.7 has the opacity under image grayed out so that when turned up or down, does not affect the image.

[image]

Hoping someone has a remedy for this, really seems like a simple command, can't believe it's this frustratingly hard to create this effect, should be a staple in modeling.

Comment: I think you have to click the Use Alpha button?

Comment: @NascentSpace That is correct. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: Do you mean Version 2.82 (sub 7)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to change the opacity level you have to turn on Use Alpha. In your screenshot it's the third field from the top.